# C++ MFC CListCtrl - How to sort item upon startup (without any UI interaction)?

Tags: c++, sorting, mfc, clistctrl

I have a list of item to be loaded in an MFC window with CListCtrl in it.
Upon OnInitDialog(), I will perform
`m_List.InsertItem(&item);`
where *this item* contains data such as: filename, last date modified, and comment.
The current output that I have now is that it will sort it with the last date modified when I open this dialog, then I would need to manually click on the list header to trigger an event to sort the data according to filename with functions such as below:

```cpp
ON_NOTIFY(LVN_COLUMNCLICK, IDC_FILELIST, OnColumnclickFilelist)

int CALLBACK CDlg::AlphaNumericSorting(LPARAM lParam1, LPARAM lParam2, LPARAM ParameterSort)
{
    std::wstring wv1(((CLVData*)lParam1)->strFileName);
    std::wstring wv2(((CLVData*)lParam2)->strFileName);
    return StrCmpLogicalW(wv1.c_str(), wv2.c_str()) < 0;
}

void Dlg::OnColumnclickFilelist(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{
     NM_LISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)pNMHDR;
     m_List.SortItems(AlphaNumericSorting, pNMListView->iSubItem);
     *pResult = 0;
}
```

Now I'm trying to make it sort automatically upon OnInitDialog(), is there a correct way to do so? From what I searched so far, all samples I got are those with event handling.

Comment: You can simply call `SortItems()` too, with the same or another comparison function. You pass the subItem as a parameter to the comparison function but do nothing with it; you should examine it there and perform the comparisons based on it, ie the subItem index. Also, the comparison function is integer, it may return a negative, zero or positive value (meaning that the 1st arg is respectively <, = or > than the 2nd one) so you should return the result of `StrCmpLogicalW()`, why put that `<0` there, this effectively makes it a boolean. You can even avoid creating those temporary string objects.

Comment: Not that it changes the specific problem asked for, but I generally find it a lot easier to manage sorting using a [virtual list-view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#virtual-list-view-style) (i.e. setting the [`LVS_OWNERDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-window-styles) style).